# refer content of one file into another file using java

Tags: java, file

Using a file operation in java, I can copy or append content of one file into another file; however, my situation is little bit different. I do not want to copy or append the contents of a file into another. I want to refer the content of one file into another.

I need something along the lines of [transclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transclusion) which is working for me in Java.
I need to be able to include or exclude content of a file whenever I want instead of appending or removing content manually each time using file operation.

By the way, my file is pure txt file. How can I perform this task in java?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most elegant way to solve such a requirement is to have a look at a templating technology like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/). Both should have native support for File inclusion.